# How does ToList() on an IEnumerable work?

Tags: c#, .net, list, ienumerable

How does the extension method `ToList()` work? Say I have an `IEnumerable` of 10000 items. Will `ToList()` create a new `List` and iterate over the `IEnumerable` of 10000 items and then return me a `List` or does .NET do it in some other way?

This [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) talks about immediate execution of a DB query. My question is only about converting `IEnumerable` to a `List`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It doesn't necessarily iterate, although that's the "worst case" scenario. Basically it calls `new List<T>(source)`, but that has some tricks up its sleeve: if the source implements `ICollection<T>`, the constructor can call [`ICollection<T>.CopyTo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0efx51xw.aspx) to copy the complete data into an array. This may well be implemented more efficiently than single-stepping iteration. Likewise in the `ICollection<T>` case, the new list knows the final size to start with, so it won't need to keep expanding its internal buffers.

For a few more details, see my [Edulinq `ToList()` blog post](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/01/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-20-tolist).

Comment: The above link is not functional. You can navigate to Jon's post here - [Edulinq ToList() blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/01/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-20-tolist/)

Comment: @vibhu: Updated the link.

Answer (score 3):

The `.ToList` extension method calls the [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0.aspx) constructor passing it the `IEnumerable<T>`. This constructor will iterate over the `IEnumerable<T>` and copy the elemtns of the `IEnumerable<T>` in the same order they are returned.